# How to globally add data to a static class in another dll

Tags: c#

In project A, i have a static class which stores data for specific types, this data is initialized in the static constructor

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> data = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    static MyStaticClass() { /*fill data here*/ }

    public static object GetData(Type type) { return data[type]; }

    public static void SetData(Type type, object o) { data[type] = o; }
}
```

Project B uses project A. Project B is also a library.
In project B i want to use this class not only for types added in the static constructor, but also for types defined in B and its dependencies.

Basically somewhere in B i want to have the following code:

```
MyStaticClass.SetData(typeof(TypeInB), new object());
MyStaticClass.SetData(typeof(TypeInDllUsedByB), new object());
```

What would be the appropriate place to put this code in project B?
I project B there are several places i'd like to call `GetData` without having to worry if previous code has already been executed.

I thought about placing it in `static TypeInB()` and any other classes i'd like to use, but that won't work for classes defined in other assemblies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create wrapper class in project B that will fwd calls to repository in project A. For example,

```
public static class MyStaticClassInB
{

    static MyStaticClassInB() { /*fill data here*/ }

    public static object GetData(Type type) { return MyStaticClass.GetData(type); }

    public static void SetData(Type type, object o) { MyStaticClass.SetData(type, o); }
}
```

Always use MyStaticClassInB in Project B (and not MyStaticClass). Now correct location to initialize types from B would be static constructor of this class.

Comment: so just take the class from project A and put it into project b?

Comment: @Spooks, not really - I am advising to create a wrapper that will forward call to class from project A. There can be multiple methods in that class and they have non-trivial implementation and I am suggesting to re-use it rather than copy it.